# ServerError: TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I'm trying to do signIn with nextauth.js.

My code is given below:

```html
import { getProviders, signIn as SignIntoProvider } from 'next-auth/react'
import Header from '../../Components/Header'

function signIn({ providers }) {
    return (
        <>
            <Header />
            {Object.values(providers).map((provider) => {
                return (
                    <div key={provider.name}>
                        <button onClick={() => SignIntoProvider(provider.id)}>
                            Sign in with {provider.name}
                        </button>
                    </div>
                )
            })
            }
        </>
    )
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
    const providers = await getProviders();

    return {
        props: {
            providers
        },
    }
}

export default signIn
```

I'm getting this error. I paste this code from NextAuth.js official website.
My error is given below:

```html
Server Error
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Source
pages\auth\signin.js (8:20) @ signIn

   6 | <>
   7 |     <Header />
>  8 |     {Object.values(providers).map((provider) => {
     |            ^
   9 |         return (
  10 |             <div key={provider.name}>
  11 |                 <button onClick={() => SignIntoProvider(provider.id)}>
```

Also I tried

```html
{providers && providers.length && Object.values(providers).map(....
```

It's return my header component only.

My nextauth url is

```html
NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000
```

Answer (score 0):

You get this behavior since `providers` is either `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: Yes, I know but any solution is there?

Comment: You wrote the solution yourself: `{providers && providers.length && Object.values(providers).map(....` will verify the existence of providers. You get Header only since there are no providers. What behavior do you expect?

Comment: I need signIn button which is inside in map function